# Am implementing a queue in python, What is making the dequeue part not to work?

Tags: python, linked-list, queue

AM Implementing a Queue in python. The code I have already done is below, but one thing am not able to figure out is how to delete the last item in the queue. My  implementation is apparently correct. What am I missing in the code

```
class Queue:

    class node:
        def __init__(self):
            self.data = None
            self.next = None

    def __init__(self):
        self.cur_node = None
        self.head = None
    def isEmpty(self):
        return self.head==None

    def push(self,data):
        new_node = self.node()
        if self.head == None:
            new_node.data=data
            new_node.next=None
            self.head = new_node
            self.cur_node = None

        else:
            new_node.data = data
            node=self.head
            self.cur_node=node
            new_node.next=self.cur_node
            self.head=new_node
        #set it to head and change current head to next



    def list_print(self):
        node = self.head
        while node:
            print (node.data)
            node = node.next

    def dequeue(self): # A Queue IMPLEMENTS ITS STRUCTURE AS FIFO ( First IN First OUT)
        if self.head == None:
            raise Exception("Queue is empty")            
        else:# Remove the  last item which entered first
            node=self.head
            prevnode=node
            nodetodel=node
            while node:
                if node.next==None:
                    nodetodel=node
                    print(node.data)
                    node=node.next
                else:
                    #print(node.data)
                    node=node.next
                    prevnode=node

            self.cur_node=prevnode
            self.cur_node.next=None
            print(node.data)
            del(node)
lyst = ["Bill", "David", "Susan", "Jane", "Kent", "Brad"]
n=Queue()
for name in lyst:
    n.push(name)
n.dequeue()
#n.list_print()
print("Done")
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are having?

Comment: the dequeue is not working as desired. the program stops at that point and the last statement `print("Done") is not output, so it means there is a problem with the delete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me as if you've implemented your `Queue` backwards. Shouldn't `head` keep track of the oldest value in the `Queue`?  Then to dequeue, you just do something like `self.head = self.head.next`.  Here's a quick implementation

```
class Queue:

    class EmptyQueue(Exception):
        def __str__(self):
            return "Queue is empty, cannot dequeue."    
    class node:
        def __init__(self, data, next):
            self.data = data
            self.next = next

    def __init__(self, seq=None): 
        self.head = None #Oldest item in queue
        self.tail = None #Youngest item in queue
        if seq:
            for item in seq:
                self.enqueue(item)

    def enqueue(self, item):
        new_node = Queue.node(item, None)
        if not self.tail: #queue empty
            self.head = new_node
            self.tail = new_node
        else:
            self.tail.next = new_node
            self.tail = new_node

    def dequeue(self):
        if self.head:
            data = self.head.data
            self.head = self.head.next
            return data
        else:
            raise Queue.EmptyQueue

    def list_print(self):
        curr = self.head
        while curr:
            print(curr.data)
            curr = curr.next
```

Comment: there is an error with this   ~ `File "C:\Users\Issaco\Documents\EC Chapter 03\jn.py", line 43, in <module>
    n.enqueue(name)
  File "     ----\jn.py", line 18, in enqueue
    new_node = node(item, None)
NameError: name 'node' is not defined`

Comment: @BroNick you can either move the two class definitions out of `Queue` or call them like `Queue.node(...)`

Answer (score 0):

The if node.next==None part in dequeue is wrong in the context of the print statement.  I think the following is more correct (I've also simplified):

```
def dequeue(self): # A Queue IMPLEMENTS ITS STRUCTURE AS FIFO ( First IN First OUT)
    if self.head == None:
        raise Exception("Queue is empty")            
    else:# Remove the  last item which entered first
        node=self.head
        prev = None
        while node:
            if node.next:
                prev = node = node.next
            else:
                self.cur_node = prev
                if prev:
                    prev.next = None
                return node.data
```

But in real usage you'd probably just use the built-in list (which can be used as a queue) or the queue.queue, the later is concurrent safe.

Answer (score 0):

> What am I missing in the code

nodetodel is not used

```
        #print(node.data)
        node=node.next
        prevnode=node
```

You should set prevnode before changing node, not after.

```
    self.cur_node=prevnode
    self.cur_node.next=None
```

cur_node is useless as member variable, you don't use it in any condition, local variable will do this work easily and you already have one (prevnode)

```
    print(node.data)
    del(node)
```

By the time of execution of these 2 lines you already have node==None and it's the cause of program crash. Probably you wanted to use nodetodel intead.

P.S. I'm just pointing out what you missed in your code - as you asked. I hope it will be helpful, even though I personally believe after fixes and making sure it can work somehow you'll think about @PatrickHaugh answer and start over from scratch.

You implementation of queue is quite inefficient, as it has to traverse through every element of linked list. The key to optimization in head/tail keeping is to avoid requirement for getting through the whole list to perform push/pop.